# DOMpdf, adding a new page to PDF

Tags: php, dompdf

Is it possible to add a new page in DOMpdf? Similar to mPDF AddPage(); functionaly. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation, is there any work around to this?

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: One possible answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27658136/1883256)

Answer (score 80):

dompdf takes care of paging automagically. If you want to force a page break you can do so by styling an element with `page-break-before: always;` or `page-break-after: always;`.

Comment: But where do you type that code? Any _further_ and _deeper_ example?

Comment: @pathros that's standard CSS, so you would style the element you want with those declarations, either inline or in a stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you Brian <3

Answer (score 67):

Just an example for BrianS's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768573/3411766):

CSS

```
.page_break { page-break-before: always; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="page_break"></div>
```

Comment: If you having issue where an extra blank page is added at the end, it is actually caused by the newline that comes after the closing </div> tag. Putting both the </body> and </html> on the same line as the last </div> will solve the issue.

Answer (score 15):

All answers presented here will make DomPDF to add a blank page to the end of the PDF file. Here is how to fix that:

CSS:

```
div.page_break + div.page_break{
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page_break"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the newline that comes after the closing </div> tag. Putting both the </body> and </html> on the same line as the last </div> will also work.

Answer (score 11):

may be will be helpfull for auto generation some pages

```
<div class="wrapper-page">
    ... page content ...    
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper-page {
    page-break-after: always;
}

.wrapper-page:last-child {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility

Answer (score 4):

If the other answer doesn't work for you (as it is for me), you can add a CSS class :

```
.page { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

and encapsulate every "page" in an element with this class. Not the prettiest way, but it does the job.