# How to generate multiple copies of same PDF file in dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using `dompdf` to generate invoices, one invoice is generated but I want to generate 3 copies of same invoice pdf file which is copy1, copy2, copy3. Each copy should start on new page of the same pdf file.

```
$dompdf = PDF::loadView('admin.pdf.invoice', compact('data'));
$options = [];
$options['isHtml5ParserEnabled'] = true;
$options['isRemoteEnabled'] = true;
$options['isPhpEnabled'] = true;
$dompdf->setOptions($options);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$file =LOCAL_PDF_PATH."invoice.pdf";
$dompdf->save(LOCAL_PDF_PATH."invoice.pdf");
```

Comment: So would a [file copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) do the trick for you?

Comment: `$dompdf->save(LOCAL_PDF_PATH."invoice1.pdf"); 
$dompdf->save(LOCAL_PDF_PATH."invoice2.pdf"); 
$dompdf->save(LOCAL_PDF_PATH."invoice3.pdf");` ?

Comment: Since the OP add a comment to clarify that he would like to have all the copy in the same file, then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746958/dompdf-adding-a-new-page-to-pdf . and just triple your duplicate your `loadView` 3 times ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $dompdf = PDF::loadView('admin.pdf.invoice', compact('data'));
    $options = [];
    $options['isHtml5ParserEnabled'] = true;
    $options['isRemoteEnabled'] = true;
    $options['isPhpEnabled'] = true;
    $dompdf->setOptions($options);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $file =LOCAL_PDF_PATH."invoice.pdf";
    $dompdf->save(LOCAL_PDF_PATH."invoice".$i.".pdf"); 
}
```

Comment: But i want all copies in one pdf file, every copy should be start with new page and each of them should have name like for receipient,for transportor and one for supplier

Answer (score 0):

Use array chunk for that inside your view

```
$columns = 3; // number of columns on a page
// calculate number of rows and break the data into chunks
$num_rows = ceil(count($data) / $columns);
$data = array_chunk($data,$num_rows);
```